# Scheduling spark jobs on a timely basis

Tags: oozie, airflow, luigi, azkaban, mesos-chronos

Which is the recommended tool for scheduling Spark Jobs on a daily/weekly basis.
1) Oozie
2) Luigi
3) Azkaban
4) Chronos
5) Airflow

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Updating my previous answer from here: [Suggestion for scheduling tool(s) for building hadoop based data pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733441/suggestion-for-scheduling-tools-for-building-hadoop-based-data-pipelines/35758046#35758046)

- Airflow: **Try this first.** Decent UI, Python-ish job definition, semi-accessible for non-programmers, dependency declaration syntax is weird.

  - Airflow has built in support for the **fact** that jobs scheduled jobs often need to be rerun and/or backfilled. Make sure you build your pipelines to support this.
- Azkaban: Nice UI, relatively simple, accessible for non-programmers. Has a longish history at LinkedIn.

  - Azkaban enforces simplicity (can’t use features that don’t exist) and the others subtly encourage complexity.
  - Check out the Azkaban CLI project for programmatic job creation. https://github.com/mtth/azkaban (examples https://github.com/joeharris76/azkaban_examples)
- Luigi: OK UI, workflows are pure Python, requires solid grasp of Python coding and object oriented concepts, hence not suitable for non-programmers.
- Oozie: Insane XML based job definitions. Here be dragons. ;-)
- Chronos: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Philosophy:

Simpler pipelines are better than complex pipelines: Easier to create, easier to understand (especially when you didn’t create) and easier to debug/fix.

When complex actions are needed you want to encapsulate them in a way that either completely succeeds or completely fails.

If you can make it idempotent (running it again creates identical results) then that’s even better.